# OmniFaces <o:tagAttribute> not working under some circumstances

Tags: omnifaces, tagfile

I have a project where [OmniFaces 2.6.8](http://omnifaces.org/) is used. In this project I have some [facelets tag files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen#6822269), which use OmniFaces' [`<o:tagAttribute>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/tagAttribute). For some of my tagfiles I noticed *strange behavior*, which means, the `<o:tagAttribute>` seems not to be working and I get

```
IllegalStateException: Duplicate component ID 'myForm:outer' found in view.
```

as a result, because the `id`-attribute of my outer tag is not cleared and thus reused in the inner tag (just as demonstrated in OmniFaces' show-case).

I could reproduce the problem with two very simple tag-files. Here is how I use those tag-files first:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <my:outer id="outer">
    <my:inner />
  </my:outer>
</h:form>
```

And here is the complete code of the tag-files.

#### outer.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

  <o:tagAttribute name="id" />

  <h:panelGroup id="#{id}">
    <ui:insert/>
  </h:panelGroup>

</ui:composition>
```

#### inner.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

  <o:tagAttribute name="id" />

  <h:inputText id="#{id}">
    <ui:insert/>
  </h:inputText>

</ui:composition>
```

I noticed, that the problem does not arise, as soon as I change `inner.xhtml` to use `<h:outputText>` instead of `<h:inputText>`. It also disappears, when I add a `value`-attribute to the `<h:inputText>`.

Is this a bug in OmniFaces, or am I doing something wrong?
(**Update**: I created an [issue](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/475) in the OmniFaces bugtracker.)

#### My environment

- OmniFaces 2.6.8
- Mojarra 2.2.15
- Wildfly 10.1.0.Final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/475) in OmniFaces 2.6.8, which was fixed (but not mentioned in the changelog) in OmniFaces 2.6.9. Exchanging the dependency version of OmniFaces is enough to solve the described problem.

**Update:** Note, that there is also a [related issue](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/478), which was [fixed in 2.7.1](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/whatsnew#fixed_2_7_1).